# Using factory pattern to create email templates

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Firstly I try to explain my model.

I have 3 type of notifications which can have N types of email templates related to a specific status.

```
NotifySupervisor(Vacation vacation);
NotifyAdministration(Vacation vacation);
NotifyApplicant(Vacation vacation);
```

I've created a type of Factory. I don't consider this a Factory Pattern because I think it's not and I'm trying to find the propoer pattern.

Here is the "Factory":

```
public class VacationNotificationTemplateFactory : IVacationNotificationTemplateFactory
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public VacationNotificationTemplateFactory(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }

    public VacationNotificationSupervisorTemplate CreateSupervisorTemplate(Vacation vacation)
    {
        return new VacationNotificationSupervisorTemplate(vacation);
    }

    public VacationNotificationAdministrationTemplate CreateAdministrationTemplate(Vacation vacation)
    {
        return new VacationNotificationAdministrationTemplate(_userService, vacation);
    }

    public VacationNotificationApplicantTemplate CreateApplicantTemplate(Vacation vacation)
    {
        return new VacationNotificationApplicantTemplate(_userService, vacation);
    }
}
```

Here is how I create my templates based on the status:

```
public class VacationNotificationSupervisorTemplate : VacationNotificationTemplate
{
    public VacationNotificationSupervisorTemplate(Vacation vacation)
    {
        switch (vacation.Status)
        {
            case VacationStatus.Cancelling:

                Subject = CancellingTemplateSubject;
                Body = "Für Mitarbeiter {0} liegt ein Urlaubsstornierung für den Zeitraum {1} bis {2} vor.\n\n Bitte geben Sie den Antrag im Timesheet frei oder lehnen Sie diesen ab. \n\n";
                break;

            case VacationStatus.Open:
            case VacationStatus.Approved:

                Subject = RequestTemplateSubject;
                Body = "Für Mitarbeiter {0} liegt ein Urlaubsantrag bzw. Gleitzeitantrag für den Zeitraum {1} bis {2} vor.\n\n Bitte geben Sie den Antrag im Timesheet frei oder lehnen Sie diesen ab. \n\n";
                break;

            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }
}

public class VacationNotificationApplicantTemplate : VacationNotificationTemplate
{
    public VacationNotificationApplicantTemplate(IUserService userService, Vacation vacation)
    {
        var currentUser = userService.GetCurrentUser();

        Subject = "Urlaubsantrag wurde {0}";
        Body = $"Dein Antrag({vacation.Type}) vom {vacation.StartDate.ToShortDateString()} bis {vacation.EndDate.ToShortDateString()} wurde von {currentUser.Name} genehmigt";

        switch (vacation.Status)
        {
            case VacationStatus.Rejected:
                Subject = string.Format(Subject, "abgelehnt");
                break;

            case VacationStatus.Approved:
                Subject = string.Format(Subject, "genehmigt");
                break;

            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }
}

public class VacationNotificationAdministrationTemplate : VacationNotificationTemplate
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public VacationNotificationAdministrationTemplate(IUserService userService, Vacation vacation)
    {
        _userService = userService;

        switch (vacation.Status)
        {
            case VacationStatus.Cancelling:

                Attachment = CreateAttachment(vacation, "UAntragStorno_ID{0}.xml");
                Subject = CancellingTemplateSubject;
                Body = "Für Mitarbeiter {0} liegt ein Urlaubsstornierung für den Zeitraum {1} bis {2} vor.\n\n Bitte löschen Sie diese E-Mail nicht, solange die Daten nicht importiert wurden. \n\n";

                break;

            case VacationStatus.Open:
            case VacationStatus.Approved:

                Attachment = CreateAttachment(vacation, "UAntragStorno_ID{0}.xml");
                Subject = RequestTemplateSubject;
                Body = "Für Mitarbeiter {0} liegt ein ein Urlaubsantrag bzw. Gleitzeitantrag für den Zeitraum {1} bis {2} vor.\n\n Bitte löschen Sie diese E-Mail nicht, solange die Daten nicht importiert wurden. \n\n";

                break;

            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }

    #region Private Methods

    private Attachment CreateAttachment(Vacation vacation, string name)
    {
        var applicant = _userService.GetUserById(vacation.ApplicantId);

        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        var writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);

        writer.Write(CreateXmlTemplate(vacation, applicant));
        writer.Flush();
        memoryStream.Position = 0;

        var contentType = new ContentType(MediaTypeNames.Text.Xml);
        var vacationAttachment = new Attachment(memoryStream, contentType) { Name = string.Format(name, vacation.Id) };

        return vacationAttachment;
    }

    private static string CreateXmlTemplate(Vacation vacation, User applicant)
    {
        var vacationType = vacation.Status == VacationStatus.Cancelling ? "storno" : "antrag";

        var id = $"ID{vacation.Id}";

        var userName = applicant.Name.Trim().Split(',');
        var userFirstName = userName[1];
        var userLastName = userName[0];

        const string XmlTemplate = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"iso-8859-1\"?><urlaubsantrag xmlns:dt=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes:dt\" xml:space=\"preserve\">" +
                                   "<itemtype dt:dt=\"string\">{0}</itemtype>" +
                                   "<szFirma dt:dt=\"string\">Company AG</szFirma>" +
                                   "<szPersonalnummer dt:dt=\"string\">{1}</szPersonalnummer>" +
                                   "<szName dt:dt=\"string\">{2}</szName>" +
                                   "<szVorname dt:dt=\"string\">{3}</szVorname>" +
                                   "<datVon dt:dt=\"datetime\">{4}</datVon>" +
                                   "<datBis dt:dt=\"datetime\">{5}</datBis>" +
                                   "<lid_fehlzeitart dt:dt=\"i4\">{6}</lid_fehlzeitart>" +
                                   "<typ dt:dt=\"string\">{7}</typ>" +
                                   "<anmerkung dt:dt=\"string\">{8}</anmerkung>" +
                                   "<kennung dt:dt=\"string\">{9}</kennung></urlaubsantrag>";

        return string.Format(XmlTemplate, vacationType, applicant.InternalNumber, userLastName, userFirstName, vacation.StartDate.ToString("O"), vacation.EndDate.ToString("O"), (int)vacation.Type, "Ganztags", string.Empty, id);
    }

    #endregion Private Methods
}
```

The base class:

```
public abstract class VacationNotificationTemplate
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    public string Body { get; set; }

    public Attachment Attachment { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the usage:

```
_vacationNotificationTemplateFactory.CreateApplicantTemplate(vacation);
_vacationNotificationTemplateFactory.CreateSupervisorTemplate(vacation);    
_vacationNotificationTemplateFactory.CreateAdministrationTemplate(vacation);
```

From my point of view it's not that bad, problem is I'm trying to find a name for this pattern or trying to find the perfect patter that suits for this case.

Comment: Each notification works with a Vacation object and has its own types of templates. Sounds like [Abstract Factory Pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) I mean, it could fit, not that what you have is AFP

Comment: @OguzOzgul That is also my thought. I just cannot apply it somehow, maybe because of the switch cases in the templates, but I'm still trying.

Comment: Where is the decision for the notification type (admin, supervisor, applicant) made? For the template bodies, I would prefer keeping them in resources and you could access the resource with key and a suffix like Resources["AdminTemplate" + VacationStatus]

Comment: @OguzOzgul - it seems like `Abstract Factory` is working pretty good, I'm progressing. About the body, resources? Hmmmm...  You might be right, I still didn't think about that, but I'll give it a god, sounds good tho!

Answer (score 7):

There are two things "wrong" with your Abstract Factory pattern. Neither of them are terrible, but it does mean that you've not implemented the pattern, but some other type of factory that I don't have a name for.

1. The factory should return an instance of the base class or interface. Yours returns a concrete instance of the particular type.
2. The factory itself should adhere to an interface and be broken into one factory class for each concrete type.

For example:

```
public interface IVacationNotificationTemplateFactory
{
    IVacationNotificationTemplate Create();
}

public class VacationNotificationSupervisorTemplateFactory : IVacationNotificationTemplateFactory
{
    IVacationNotificationTemplate Create()
    {
        return new VacationNotificationSupervisorTemplate(_userService);
    }
}

public class VacationNotificationApplicantTemplateFactory : IVacationNotificationTemplateFactory
{
    IVacationNotificationTemplate Create()
    {
        return new VacationNotificationApplicantTemplate();
    }
 }
```

[There's lots of good reading and examples on Wikipedia.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)

---

The other thing I notice is all of the strings embedded in the code. I recently built something similar and had a tough time creating tests that weren't brittle. What I ended up doing was storing the strings in html files, keeping the string formatting stuff in there as well. Then I'd load the file at runtime and "bind" it via string formatting. It makes it feel and act much more like a view than some output that needs to be tested.

Speaking of, be sure to HTML encode any string variables that you're injecting into the templates. Otherwise, you'll end up with invalid HTML in the email body. There's a utility method in the `System.Web.UI` namespace for it. (I'm just assuming you're using HTML mail, my apologies if you're not.)

I'd consider using a more formal, *and strongly typed* method of building your XML though. There are several libraries to do this in the .Net framework, so I'll leave that choice to you, but my personal favorite way is with Linq-to-XML.

Comment: I’d actually like to update my advice. If you’re creating HTML mail, use the Razor view engine to generate it. Life is much simpler that way.

Answer (score 4):

There are two major problems with your approach.

1. What happens if you have more types of employee and vacation? Or How do you remove a type of employee and vacation when it's no longer needed? Moreover, there are more conditions introduced aside from employee type and vacation status. As a result, you have to make a lot of changes to the existing code when either of these cases happens.
2. Your email template engine is impossible to reuse because it's tightly coupled to Employee and Vacation models.

You could associate your problem with the **MVC** pattern. Where your email template is the View, and your model is all necessary values populated into the template. A note that this code is written in Java, but it's very similar to C#

```
// Represent an email. It holds data only, not provide any operation.
interface Email {
   String getSubject();
   String getBody();
   Attachment getAttachment();
}

// Combine an email template with model data together to produce an email
interface EmailRender() {
   Email render(EmailTemplate template, Map<String, Object> model)
}

// Represent an email template. Similar to Email, no operation should be provided here
interface EmailTemplate {
    String getSubject();
    String getBody();
    Attachment getAttchment();
}
```

I don't post implementations because it makes difficult to follow the concept here. Basically, **EmailRender** is consisted of a template engine which is used to replace placeholders in **EmailTemplate** with values from **model**.

The only matter left is how do we figure out the appropriate template for an employee. If you look deeply, you will see that you're selecting an email template based on a set of conditions, particularly employee type and vacation status. So I strongly recommend you use the **Table-driven Method** strategy. It gives you many benefits about readability, maintainability and testability. On top of that, you get rid of a significant amount of if/else/switch blocks

```
interface VacationEmailTemplateResolver {
     EmailTemplate resolve(EmployeeType employeeType, VacationStatus vacationStatus);
}

class TableVacationEmailTemplateResolver implements VacationEmailTemplateResolver {
    @Override
    public EmailTemplate resolve(EmployeeType employeeType, VacationStatus vacationStatus) {

        // query from database
        // select * from vacation_email_template
        // where employee_type = {employeeType} and vacation_status = vacation_status

    }
}
```

I suggest you store templates into database only because it enables you to modify templates and conditions at run time. If you think it's overkill, you could go with memory or even a csv file.

Here is the usage:

```
EmailRender emailRender = new DefaultEmailRender()
VacationEmailTemplateResolver templateResolver = new TableVacationEmailTemplateResolver();
EmailTemplate template = templateResolver.resolve(employeeType, vacationStatus);
Email email = emailRender.render(template, model);
```

Comment: this would work good only by using database otherwise the `resolve method` would have to handle the switch case for vacationStatus and here is where the factory comes! But yeah, I understand your approach and is good also. Answering to your question - If I have a new vacation status I just add a new factory "StatusNameFactory" that inherits from TemplateFactoryBase and that is it. And for every template I just need a class that inherits from TemplateBase. Pretty straightforward, but of course there is always a way to make it better. Thanks for sharing your knowledge!

Comment: @DanielGroh
I mentioned before we don't need a database table for storing email templates. All you need is a concrete implementation of EmailTemplate called VacationEmailTemplate, which has two extra fields, employee type and vacation status. From there, you initialize a list of VacationEmailTemplate corresponding to given conditions. Finally, a simple lambda: `vacationEmailTemplate.filter(template -> template.employeeType == employeeType && template.vacationStatus == vacationStatus)`

Comment: You have to distinguish between duplicate code and duplicate data. In your case, your email templates luckily share some common values. It will be a disaster if an email template is completely to each other.

Comment: I think your approach is better, but for me is also a factory pattern (what you are calling resolve) with the difference that you use projection to query the template from some source!

Comment: I agree it's some sorts of a building pattern as long as it creates a new object. The difference you pointed out is called [Data-driven programming or Table-driven method](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DataDrivenPrograms) which is used to determine the control flow based on an input.

Comment: Very good answer! This is essentially what I alluded to when I spoke about binding to a template.

Answer (score -1):

The solution was indeed [Abstract Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern#C.23_Example) even though I ran into 2 empty classes which in my opnion can be kept for now as my code is still under construction and I'm pretty sure I'm going to fill thoses classes up.

Here is how I have my `Abstract Factory`:

```
public abstract class TemplateFactoryBase
{
    public abstract SupervisorTemplateBase CreateSupervisorTemplate();

    public abstract ApplicantTemplateBase CreateApplicantTemplate();

    public abstract AdministrationTemplateBase CreateAdministrationTemplate();
}
```

Here are my abstract `Templates`:

```
public abstract class TemplateBase
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    public string Body { get; set; }

    public Attachment Attachment { get; set; }
}

public abstract class SupervisorTemplateBase : TemplateBase
{
    // TODO: Get rid of this if not implemented
}

public abstract class ApplicantTemplateBase : TemplateBase
{
    // TODO: Get rid of this if not implemented
}

public abstract class AdministrationTemplateBase : TemplateBase
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    protected AdministrationTemplateBase(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }

    protected Attachment CreateAttachment(Vacation vacation, string name)
    {
        var applicant = _userService.GetUserById(vacation.ApplicantId);

        return Attachment.CreateAttachmentFromString(CreateXmlTemplate(vacation, applicant), string.Format(name, vacation.Id));
    }

    #region Private Methods

    private static string CreateXmlTemplate(Vacation vacation, User applicant)
    {
        var vacationType = vacation.Status == VacationStatus.Cancelling ? "storno" : "antrag";

        var id = $"ID{vacation.Id}";

        var userName = applicant.Name.Trim().Split(',');
        var userFirstName = userName[1];
        var userLastName = userName[0];

        const string XmlTemplate = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"iso-8859-1\"?><urlaubsantrag xmlns:dt=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes:dt\" xml:space=\"preserve\">" +
                                   "<itemtype dt:dt=\"string\">{0}</itemtype>" +
                                   "<szFirma dt:dt=\"string\">conplement AG</szFirma>" +
                                   "<szPersonalnummer dt:dt=\"string\">{1}</szPersonalnummer>" +
                                   "<szName dt:dt=\"string\">{2}</szName>" +
                                   "<szVorname dt:dt=\"string\">{3}</szVorname>" +
                                   "<datVon dt:dt=\"datetime\">{4}</datVon>" +
                                   "<datBis dt:dt=\"datetime\">{5}</datBis>" +
                                   "<lid_fehlzeitart dt:dt=\"i4\">{6}</lid_fehlzeitart>" +
                                   "<typ dt:dt=\"string\">{7}</typ>" +
                                   "<anmerkung dt:dt=\"string\">{8}</anmerkung>" +
                                   "<kennung dt:dt=\"string\">{9}</kennung></urlaubsantrag>";

        return string.Format(XmlTemplate, vacationType, applicant.InternalNumber, userLastName, userFirstName, vacation.StartDate.ToString("O"), vacation.EndDate.ToString("O"), (int)vacation.Type, "Ganztags", string.Empty, id);
    }

    #endregion Private Methods
}
```

And here my concrete `Templates`:

```
public class CancellingAdministrationTemplate : AdministrationTemplateBase
{
    public CancellingAdministrationTemplate(Vacation vacation, IUserService userService)
        : base(userService)
    {
        Attachment = CreateAttachment(vacation, "UAntragStorno_ID{0}.xml");
        Subject = "Urlaubsstornierung";
        Body = "Für Mitarbeiter {0} liegt ein Urlaubsstornierung für den Zeitraum {1} bis {2} vor.\n\n Bitte löschen Sie diese E-Mail nicht, solange die Daten nicht importiert wurden. \n\n";
    }
}

public class CancellingSupervisorTemplate : SupervisorTemplateBase
{
    public CancellingSupervisorTemplate()
    {
        Subject = "Urlaubsstornierung";
        Body = "Für Mitarbeiter {0} liegt ein Urlaubsstornierung für den Zeitraum {1} bis {2} vor.\n\n Bitte geben Sie den Antrag im Timesheet frei oder lehnen Sie diesen ab. \n\n";
    }
}

public class RejectedApplicantTemplate : ApplicantTemplateBase
{
    public RejectedApplicantTemplate(Vacation vacation, IUserService userService)
    {
        var currentUser = userService.GetCurrentUser();

        Subject = "Urlaubsantrag wurde abgelehnt";
        Body = $"Dein Antrag({vacation.Type}) vom {vacation.StartDate.ToShortDateString()} bis {vacation.EndDate.ToShortDateString()} wurde von {currentUser.Name} abgelehnt";
    }
}

public class RequestAdministrationTemplate : AdministrationTemplateBase
{
    public RequestAdministrationTemplate(Vacation vacation, IUserService userService)
        : base(userService)
    {
        Attachment = CreateAttachment(vacation, "UAntragStorno_ID{0}.xml");
        Subject = "Urlaubsantrag";
        Body = "Für Mitarbeiter {0} liegt ein ein Urlaubsantrag bzw. Gleitzeitantrag für den Zeitraum {1} bis {2} vor.\n\n Bitte löschen Sie diese E-Mail nicht, solange die Daten nicht importiert wurden. \n\n";
    }
}

public class RequestApplicantTemplate : ApplicantTemplateBase
{
    public RequestApplicantTemplate(Vacation vacation, IUserService userService)
    {
        var currentUser = userService.GetCurrentUser();

        Subject = "Urlaubsantrag wurde genehmigt";
        Body = $"Dein Antrag({vacation.Type}) vom {vacation.StartDate.ToShortDateString()} bis {vacation.EndDate.ToShortDateString()} wurde von {currentUser.Name} genehmigt";
    }
}

public class RequestSupervisorTemplate : SupervisorTemplateBase
{
    public RequestSupervisorTemplate()
    {
        Subject = "Urlaubsantrag";
        Body = "Für Mitarbeiter {0} liegt ein Urlaubsantrag bzw. Gleitzeitantrag für den Zeitraum {1} bis {2} vor.\n\n Bitte geben Sie den Antrag im Timesheet frei oder lehnen Sie diesen ab. \n\n";
    }
}
```

Here the usage:

```
public interface IVacationNotificationTemplateFactory
{
    TemplateFactoryBase CreateTemplateFor(Vacation vacation);
}

public class VacationNotificationTemplateFactory : IVacationNotificationTemplateFactory
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public VacationNotificationTemplateFactory(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }

    public TemplateFactoryBase CreateTemplateFor(Vacation vacation)
    {
        switch (vacation.Status)
        {
            case VacationStatus.Open:
            case VacationStatus.Approved:
                return new RequestTemplateFactory(vacation, _userService);

            case VacationStatus.Cancelling:
                return new CancellingTemplateFactory(vacation, _userService);

            case VacationStatus.Rejected:
                return new RejectedTemplateFactory(vacation, _userService);

            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }
}
```

So in some constructor I just have to inject this interface and call it, just like that:

```
private readonly IVacationNotificatonTemplateFactory _vacationNotificationTemplateFactory;

public MyConstructor(IVacationNotificationTemplateFactory vacationNotificationTemplateFactory){
    _vacationNotificationTemplateFactory = vacationNotificationTemplateFactory;
}

var templateFactory = _vacationNotificationTemplateFactory.Create(vacation);

var supervisorTemplate = templateFactory.CreateSupervisorTemplate();
var administrationTemplate = templateFactory.CreateAdministrationTemplate();
var applicantTemplate = templateFactory.CreateApplicantTemplate();
```

I think I was able to achieve the main goal, that was to find a proper pattern and apply it to my need. Now I'm going to clean it up by removing embedded strings in the code and etc.

Comment: Self-answers are fine, as long as they consist of a *review of the original code*. If you would like feedback on this improved version, feel free to ask a new question.